# Nonstable $K$-theory question

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $Y$ be a compact, Hausdorff topological space, and $X$ be a locally compact, contractible, Hausdorff space which is homeomorphic to a dense subset of $Y$.

Question A: Is $GL_1(C(Y))\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} K_1(C(Y))$ surjective?

Question B: If $r:C(Y)\rightarrow C(Y\setminus X)$ denotes the restriction map, then does the following diagram commute? 
$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
GL_1(C(Y)) & \ra{r} & GL_1(C(Y\setminus X))    \\
\da{\pi} & & \da{\pi}     \\
K_1(C(Y)) & \ras{K_1(r)} & K_1(C(Y\setminus X))      \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: If $Y$ is compact, Hausdorff, and contractible then $K_1(C(Y)$ is trivial...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant $X$ is contractible. Will change that now.

Comment: $GL_1(C(Y))$ corresponds to the set of nonvanishing continuous functions on $Y$, and for connected $Y$ this deformation retracts onto $\{1, -1\}$.  So the image in $K_1(C(Y))$ is always trivial, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I follow, since $Y$ is not assumed to be connected?

Comment: Adding additional connected components will not help $\pi$ become surjective.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. So for Question A, the answer is: Not always.

Comment: @TsolEdud Are you working with real or complex matrices?

Comment: @Rasmus: Complex. Did you mean then that in the complex case the $\{1,-1\}$ reasoning above is not quite true?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Question A, the $3$-torus provides a counterexamle: its complex $K_1$-group has rank $4$ but its cohomotopy has only rank $3$. (I have learnt about this example from the book of Rordam, Larsen and Laustsen.)

The diagram in Question B clearly commutes because $K_1(r)$ just acts by picking some representative, restricting it and then taking its $K_1$-class.